# How to call function when i can't know about the signature?

Tags: c++

I Hooked target function. So when the app called the target function then it will  jump to my hooked(hacked) function. But i want to go back to (call) original target function. I have a original function's address but i can't know about signature about original function's. So i can't declare each function pointer for that. (because it is too many target functions that i want to hooked) So, I want to call original target function when my hooked function's dispose is done without declare function pointer(because i can't know that the parameter's count and types. I can know just a target function's address)
Is there have any way like use asm and so on...?

Comment: Doesn't the target function have the same parameters as the function you hooked? If not, you can always use a dissembler or debugger to figure it out.

Comment: No the target function has not same parameter with hooked function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is *very* unclear.

You should be aware of [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). They might define in which [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) some arguments are passed (and how is the result returned). Understand the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) relevant to your compiler, system, and processor. (See e.g. [this](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) for Linux/x86-64)

You need at least to know the signature of the called function at runtime.

In that case, you might use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). You'll better declare `extern "C"`  the called (C++) function (because the ABI is generally for C code).